# Trying to send an email with php both ways

Tags: php, email, web

As seen here, I have a form with email, and when a user types in their email into the email form, and clicks submit, both i will get an email with all the data they included in their form and the email that was typed by the user will get an email from me, anyone know how i can fix my code to make this double way work?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["send"])){

        $emailTo="myemail@gmail.com";
        $subject="Thank you for seeking us for help";
        $name=($_POST['fname']);
        $address=($_POST['address']);
        $email=($_POST['email']);
        $phone=($_POST['phone']);
        $message=($_POST['message']);
        $body="Name:$name \r\n Address:$address \r\n Email: $email \r\n
        Phone: $phone \r\n Message: $message";


        if (mail($emailTo,$subject,$body,$headers)){
            header('Location:Thankyou.php');
            exit;
        }else{
            echo "failure";
        }
    }else{

    }   

    if (isset($_POST["send"])){
        $email2=($_POST['email']);
        $emailTo="$email2";
        $subject="Thank you for emailing us";
        $body="Thank you";

        mail($emailTo,$subject,$body,$headers);

        }



?>
```

Ignore the headers.

Comment: Just do `$emailTo="myemail@gmail.com,{$_POST['email']}";`

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting errors? Are you testing this on a live web server, or on your local? If it's on your Local server then you probably need to change settings to allow mail function to work

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep, i got it to work.

Comment: Is this the way to send mass emails to those that sign up for newsletters and such?